# gfortran: no input files

Tags: command-line, fortran

When I was trying to run `gfortran` in a terminal, I got the error below:

```
$ gfortran
gfortran: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's not a problem of installation: it's a problem of usage

Answer (score 7):

`gfortran` is a compiler. It compiles files. You didn't provide any files for it to compile. It complained.